# Make the compiler tell me that two variables can’t have the same value

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have a list of objects that need to be loaded into my app. But the load order matters. I’ve created a var which is a part of each object that indicates the load order where the lowest number gets loaded in first. Then I’ve set the default to be 9999. I can manually set this value on each object and override the default. Currently this is where I’m at.

Should I add more objects which need to be loaded in a specific order in the future, I want to make sure there are no conflicts. It seems to me like I could do that by making each load order number on the objects unique, (i.e. no duplicate numbers in all the load order variables).

Is there a way I can make Xcode throw an error or warning if it detects that anything conforming to a protocol has the same value on a variable from that protocol as any of the other conforming objects?

Comment: You can't do this at compile time. How about a runtime check instead?

Comment: How would I do that? As in, have it run a validation on protocol conforming and if any of the vars are the same, crash the app?

Comment: Yeah, I assume you would need to sort the objects by that number at some point, right? Before you sort, check if all the numbers are unique. If they are not unique, crash the app.

Comment: Makes sense, and pretty simple solution, thanks Sweeper! I've noticed you respond to a fair bit of my questions, I really appreciate your feedback in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could list all the objects in an array literal in the order you want them loaded, and forgo the load order property entirely:

```
let objectsToLoad = [
    ObjectDescriptor("hello"),
    ObjectDescriptor("world"),
]
```

But if you have objects defined in disparate places and don't want a single unified array literal that lists them all, then I don't think you can get help from the compiler (or the linker).

In a few months, when Swift will have macros, you'll probably be able to get help from the compiler or the linker. The strategy is to use a macro to wrap each load-order constant in a macro that also generates some type definition whose name includes the constant, e.g. `enum _LoadOrder_1 {}`, `enum _LoadOrder_357 {}`, etc. Then, if you have a duplicate, either the compiler or the linker will fail due to the multiple definitions for a single identifier.

Comment: I didn't know about this linker stuff coming up. Seems like we've had some trouble with it at work in a project recently. The macro's sound super interesting. Is there a place I can learn more about them?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/search?expanded=true&q=%5Bpitch%5D%20macros%20in%3Atitle